# Ansible - problem with ansible_facts for packages in jinja template

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I try to get all installed packages with Ansible and write them in a "pretty" way to a file.
Calling the module works:

```
- name: Gather the rpm package facts
  package_facts:
    manager: auto
```

In a Jinja template I am using a loop, what works too:

```
{% for item in ansible_facts.packages %}
  {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately the simple output creates this "mess":

```
    "yum": [
        {
            "arch": "noarch",
            "epoch": null,
            "name": "yum",
            "release": "4.el8",
            "source": "rpm",
            "version": "4.2.23"
        }
    ],

    "zlib": [
        {
            "arch": "x86_64",
            "epoch": null,
            "name": "zlib",
            "release": "16.el8_2",
            "source": "rpm",
            "version": "1.2.11"
        }
    ]
```

Some of these elements are unnecassry for the current job, so the first call coming in mind was this:

```
{% for item in ansible_facts.packages %}
  {{ item.name }} {{ item.version }}
{% endfor %}
```

But this ended just in an error:

```
fatal: [somehost.example.org]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'name'"}
```

Searched through the internet, looked into the documentation of Ansible, tried various notations and nothing worked:

```
vars[item].name  
item[0].name
item["name"]
```

As last option I tried it with iteritems:

```
{% for (key,value) in ansible_facts.packages.iteritems() %}
  {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

But this ended I an error to:

```
fatal: [somehost.example.org]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'list object' has no attribute 'name'"}
```

It seems I am not smart enough to figure out the solution, can someone lend me a hand?

Sincerely,
a frustrated Ansible user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the data sample you posted, package name is the `key` and `value` is a list of 1 element comprising of a dictionary.

To get the version you have to access the first element. Like so:

```
{% for key, value in ansible_facts.packages.iteritems() %}
{{ key }} {{ value[0].version }}
{% endfor %}
```

Should render the file with package list like:

```
...
zlib 1.2.11
...
```